# Retrieve MySQL database column names (with table name) using Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

hopefully somebody will help me as this has had me scratching my head.

As most would already know of 2 easy ways of retrieving mysql query column names using coldfusion:

```
1. <cfset arrColumns = ListToArray(thequery.columnList) />
2. <cfset arrColumns = getMetaData(thequery) />
```

both of which would successfully create an array of column names (1 in alphanumeric order, 2 in order retrieved from the database).

For example:

```
<cfquery name="thequery" datasource="thedatasource">
    SELECT a.title, b.name 
    FROM tablea a
    JOIN tableb b ON b.a_id = a.id
</cfquery>
<cfset arrColumns = ListToArray(thequery.columnList) />
```

The above would successfully output an array with values:

```
arrColumns[1]: "name" 
arrColumns[2]: "title"
```

What I need it to do is to output:

```
arrColumns[1]: "tableb.name" 
arrColumns[2]: "tablea.title"
```

...basically, to include the database table name along with the column name. This has had me scratching my head for some time, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I have already searched Google and stackoverflow and found no answers.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention; because of the way I will need to manipulate the results from another page - I cannot use the "SELECT a.title AS 'tablea.title'" technique. The only way I can think of doing it is through coldfusion not MySQL. Is there such a way to do it? maybe.

Comment: Keith, you should use the [edit functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19243554/edit) to add more info.

Comment: Also, what's the reason for needing table names? It seems an odd requirement, so knowing what you're actually trying to achieve may help someone suggest another option.

Comment: Hi Peter, and thanks for your quick reply. The query is used in 2 pages

1. a page which includes a jQuery enhanced table of results for normal users to view
2. to be populated into dropdown boxes within an administrative page

Doing it this way means that if the query is changed then it will update in both pages and duplicate code won't be needed/changed.

dropdown's to choose the db table column (along with being able to choose alignment, width etc for the jQuery enhanced table). I need it to display tablename.columnname in the dropdown list as to aid the administrators of where its from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, JDBC doesn't reliably expose the table info you need, and the relevant method ([`getTableName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName%28int%29)) in ColdFusion's implementation simply raises an exception. So the short version is that you cannot do what you want, how you want to.

That said, I think you should approach things differently anyhow. The idea of having one data structure which contains both data and schema information seems... *wrong* to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach.  Put your query into a function that accepts a mandatory argument regarding the inclusion of table names.  If you have to provide them, then include them in the column alias, surrounded by double quotes.  Something like this:

```
select table1.field1 "table1.field1"
, table1.field2 "table1.field2"
etc
```